# A proper initial segment property (under the axioms of ZF)

Tags: set-theory

First, I apologize if the question is too naive.
My question is as below:

> Let $⟨A,\in⟩$ be a well-ordered set and suppose $B$ is a proper
> initial segment of $A$.  Does it imply that there exists a $\xi \in A$
> s.t $\xi$ is transitive?

I wondered since I know that there exists $ \xi \in A$ s.t  B = $\xi$ (as I assume a special case when the well-ordered relation is $\in$ and it is not true generally).

Thanks

Comment: No, $\{\omega,\omega+4\}$ is well-ordered, but the only initial segment which is transitive is $\varnothing$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila
Thanks, I haven't introduced yet to the concept of infinite ordinals, however this makes sense. I was personally trying to figure if the claim above is correct with finite ordinals (which is probably much less interesting and now I understand why).

Comment: Fine, then $\{3,7\}$ should work just as well. The well order is finite in both cases.

Comment: I see, this clarifies the importance of the transitive property as well to maintain the ordinal structure.

Comment: Or better yet, $\{x,\{x\}\}$, where $x$ is not even a transitive set.